# disconnecting from mongoDb with C++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb

i'm sure this must be really simple or i'm missing the point, but how do you disconnect from Mongo using the C++ driver and DBClientConnection? DBClient has a public member of 'connect' but no disconnect/kill/drop etc that I can find.

There is some talk (in stack overflow and on the web) of using ScopedDBConnection which does seem to be able to allow me to drop my connection  - but there are very few examples of how it would be used - or info on when I should use that class over the DBClientConnection class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a DBClientConnection, it has one connection, and you aren't supposed to disconnect/reconnect. I guess it kills the connection when it calls the destructors. You can set it up to automatically reconnect so you can keep using it if it loses its connection.

If you want to have connection pooling and multiple connections, you want to use ScopedDBConnection. You can see some examples here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/client/model.cpp

Here's the gist:

```
ScopedDbConnection conn("localhost");
mongo::BSONObjBuilder obj;
obj.append( "name" , "asd" );
conn->insert("test.test", obj);
conn.done();
```

Basically, you can do anything with `conn` that you can do with a DBClientConnection, but when you're done you call `done()`.